# Copy folder in client machine using jsp applet

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I am running an applet that will copy jar file in client machine .I am able to copy jar files using applet but when i am calling same Applet using jsp Appet is  not working.
Any idea how to perform that operation.
I have singed my applet and i am not getting any exception also.

```
package APPLET;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class SET_UPFILE extends Applet {


    public void init() {
        File sourceFile = new File("G:\\KERALA\\ojdbc14.jar");
        File destinationFile = new File("G:\\backup\\" + sourceFile.getName());
        SET_UPFILE copyFileExample1 = new SET_UPFILE();
        copyFileExample1.copyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
    }

    public void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destinationFile) {
        //   System.setSecurityManager(null);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

            int bufferSize;
            byte[] bufffer = new byte[512];
            while ((bufferSize = fileInputStream.read(bufffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(bufffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my jsp page calling that applet

```
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.text.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//HI"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>applet</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function startApplet(id) {
                var Projectpath="";
                var ProjectPath = document.getElementById('Projectpath').value;
                alert(ProjectPath);
                id = ProjectPath+"//"+ProjectPath;
                appletsource="<applet code='APPLET.SET_UPFILE.class' \n\
                               name='QuantumAeonGENIE1' \n\
                               id = 'QuantumAeonGENIE1'     \n\
                               codebase='./'   \n\
                               archive='MYAPPLET.jar' \n\
                               width='500' height='500' >\n";
                appletsource+="<PARAM name='message' value='"+id+"'>\n";
                appletsource+="</applet>\n";
                document.getElementById("appletdiv").innerHTML=appletsource;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body leftmargin="0px" topmargin="0px" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" SCROLL=NO>
        <form name="frmEntry" id="frmEntry" onsubmit="frmSave" method="post">
            <div id="MainDIvReport" align="center">
                <div id="FieldDiv">
                    <div id="toPrint1"
                         <center>
                            <div id="TitleDivReport" align="center">
                                <b>ETM ISSUES AND AUDIT -> TICKET DOWNLOAD</b>
                            </div>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div id="appletdiv" style="text-align: center;">

                    </div>
                    <%
                        File sourceFile = new File("");
                        String StrPath = sourceFile.getAbsolutePath();
                       // System.out.println(StrPath);
                    %>
                    <input type="hidden" id="Projectpath" name="Projectpath" value="<%=StrPath%>" ></input>
                    <table border="1" id="CntrlTABREPORT">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="width: 85%;">
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" style="width: 15%;">
                                <div  align="center" id="CntrlDivReport">
                                    <table id="tab-button">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="button" id="QAGenieCheckstatus" name="QAGenieCheckstatus" value="STATUS"  onclick="startApplet(id)" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    <center><h1></h1></center>
                </div>
                <div id="toPrint">
                    <div style="display: none;">
                        <jsp:include flush="true" page="/DROPDOWN_1.jsp"></jsp:include>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div-display-outer">
                        <div id="div-display">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  
        </form>

        <table border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#085DAD" id="div-footer">
            <tr>
                <td valign="bottom" align="center">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"Applet using jsp Appet is not working."*  Give it a good night's rest and try it in the morning, maybe it is just sleepy.  But seriously, how do you expect anyone to help you solve this without the details of the failure?  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: Dear thanks for the reply I have added java and jsp code .please have a look on that and suggest me necessary changes.

Comment: Don't call me 'dear'.  Reread my comment.  What is the console output?

Comment: I did the same thing after enabling java console from the control panel program worked.Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  You should either delete the question, or enter an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution..I am not sure but when i enabled java console output from control pannel  and then ran the same code it just worked.